# Set binlog for Mysql 5.6 & Ubuntu16.4

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, mysql-5.6, mysqlbinlog, mysql-variables

in /etc/mysql/my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
log_bin=mysql-bin
binlog_format=ROW
server-id=11
```

then on mysql client:

```
mysql> show variables like '%binlog%';
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name                           | Value                |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
| binlog_cache_size                       | 32768                |
| binlog_checksum                         | CRC32                |
| binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates | OFF                  |
| binlog_format                           | STATEMENT            |
| binlog_max_flush_queue_time             | 0                    |
| binlog_order_commits                    | ON                   |
| binlog_row_image                        | FULL                 |
| binlog_rows_query_log_events            | OFF                  |
| binlog_stmt_cache_size                  | 32768                |
| innodb_api_enable_binlog                | OFF                  |
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog          | OFF                  |
| max_binlog_cache_size                   | 18446744073709547520 |
| max_binlog_size                         | 1073741824           |
| max_binlog_stmt_cache_size              | 18446744073709547520 |
| sync_binlog                             | 0                    |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have googled "my.cnf dont take effect" and got "Changes to my.cnf don't take effect (Ubuntu 16.04, mysql 5.6)"
[Changes to my.cnf don't take effect (Ubuntu 16.04, mysql 5.6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38288646/changes-to-my-cnf-dont-take-effect-ubuntu-16-04-mysql-5-6)

I have tested the two answers. But when I start mysql with `sudo service mysql start`, there always be this error:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql[27197]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
/etc/init.d/mysql[27197]: [61B blob data]
/etc/init.d/mysql[27197]: error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
/etc/init.d/mysql[27197]: Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
/etc/init.d/mysql[27197]: 
mysql[26527]:    ...fail!
systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
```

I have spent two days searching answers, and still not find nothing helpful. Could any one  please help me out? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Reinstall MySQL

   Clean MySQL according to : 
   https://askubuntu.com/questions/172514/how-do-i-uninstall-mysql

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-* mysql-client-core-*
   sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   sudo apt-get autoclean
   ```

   as well as  https://www.jianshu.com/p/c76b31df5d09

   ```
   dpkg -l |grep ^rc|awk '{print $2}' |sudo xargs dpkg -P
   ```

   Install by `sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6`
2. Make changes in `my.cnf` take effect

   Second answer by Keeth(user:20588) on
   [Changes to my.cnf don't take effect (Ubuntu 16.04, mysql 5.6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38288646/changes-to-my-cnf-dont-take-effect-ubuntu-16-04-mysql-5-6)
3. Configure `binlog` by editing `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

   ```
       [mysqld]
       log_bin=mysql-bin
       binlog_format=ROW
       server-id=11
   ```